# Are anchor back links without text effective for SEO or black hat?

Tags: seo, html, backlinks, hyperlink

```
<a href="http://example.com" title="my keyword"></a>
```

Can I build back links like this?

Is this black hat or white hat?

Comment: How can this be considered "good"? Is this link visible to the user?

Comment: Stop thinking in terms of tricks please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you surely have already understood, this is not a good way of building backlinks. That's why I would say it is part of blackhat techniques.

A little advice: when you build a backlink, think about users first. Only put useful links for users and don't try to trick your SEO because otherwise, you will most probably get a Google penalty someday.

Answer (score 3):

Google would consider a link with no anchor text to be a "hidden link".   Google has a [hidden text and links](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66353?hl=en) page in their webmaster guidelines that calls out a slightly less egregious case as black hat:

> Hiding a link by only linking one small character—for example, a hyphen in the middle of a paragraph